# Configuring Weblogic Server for X.509 Smart Card Authentication

Tags: weblogic

I am running Oracle Weblogic 11g (10.3.6) and attempting to configure two-way SSL (client certificate requested and enforced). The client certificate is on a smart card.

I have enabled "basic" ssl in the weblogic server, and used keytool to import the relevant root CA certificates into the DemoTruststore.jks file. I have set the Two-way client cert behavior to Client Certs Requested and Enforced for the server.

Unfortunately, attempting to access my application causes the following:

```
<Certificate chain received from 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 was incomplete.> 
<NO_CERTIFICATE alert was received from 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1. Verify the SSL configuration has a proper SSL certificate chain and private key specified.>
<Certificate chain received from 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 was incomplete.>
```

The ActivClient dialog never appears to select a certificate from the Smart Card, and a pin is never requested. Therefore, I think I misconfigured something.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had forgotten I asked this, so I couldn't prove an answer. Here are the steps I took to set this up:

1. Log into the weblogic console, http://whateveryourhostnameis.com:7001/console. You'll have to know your username and password (I won't know it)
2. Click on the Servers link, then the name of your actual server instance. (A dev box with weblogic will probably only have one)
3. On the general tab, click the "SSL Listen Port Enabled". Click save.
4. On the SSL tab, click the Advanced arrow to open up the advanced options.
5. Change the "Two Way Client Cert Behavior" to "Client Certs Requested and Enforced"
6. Check the box for "Use JSSE SSL"

Even though the server might say a restart is not required, keep in mind it's an Oracle product and thus inherently evil. I recommend a server restart.

Comment: Thank you so much man!  Oracle products are definitely evil!  What is JSSE SSL? The Oracle documentation is evil too and doesn't say.